# How to set Node.js Windows Universal app as startup app on Windows 10 IOT Core

Tags: node.js, win-universal-app, raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core

I have created the sample `Hello, World Node.js Windows Universal Sample` from the [Microsoft IOT Github page](http://ms-iot.github.io/content/win10/samples/NodejsWU.htm), but now I want to set this background app to start.

I know I'm supposed to use `iotstartup`, but what is my app name?  All I see is this:

```
[10.10.xx.xx]: PS C:\> iotstartup list
Headed   : 0ea49cba-1455-4d46-82bf-e3500f805e6b_wzgz7s44cm19c!App
Headed   : 135bb3b6-419d-4692-a777-c9131bc0a419_wzgz7s44cm19c!App
Headed   : DefaultApp_cw5n1h2txyewy!App
Headed   : IoTCoreDefaultApp_hz258y3tkez3a!App
Headed   : Windows.MiracastView_cw5n1h2txyewy!Microsoft.Windows.MiracastView
Headed   : ZWaveBackgroundService_6efsg6e0hggwa!App
Headless : ZWaveBackgroundService_1.0.0.0_arm__6efsg6e0hggwa
Headless : 0ea49cba-1455-4d46-82bf-e3500f805e6b_1.0.0.0_arm__wzgz7s44cm19c
Headless : 135bb3b6-419d-4692-a777-c9131bc0a419_1.0.0.0_arm__wzgz7s44cm19c
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found an at least partial answer.  When you run the app on a "Remote machine" via Visual Studio, you can see the package name in the Build output window as the `Full Package Name`:

```
1>------ Deploy started: Project: Win10DropDoorScanner, Configuration: Debug ARM ------
1>Updating the layout...
1>Copying files: Total <1 mb to layout...
1>Deployment complete (7568ms). Full package name: "413be5f8-0fdf-4d23-a0dc-94eca103ac6b_1.0.0.0_arm__wzgz7s44cm19c"
========== Deploy: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```